# Is String NULL always equal to another String NULL in C#?

Tags: c#, string

On my VS 2015 compiler, I tested that

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str1 = null;
        string str2 = null;
        if(str1==str2)  //they are the same on my machine
        {
        }
    }
```

But this is a documented behavior? `NULL` by definition, is an undefined behavior, so comparing `NULL` to another `NULL` *could* be undefined. It could happen that on my machine, using my current .Net framework, the two `NULL`s turn out to be the same. But in the future, they *could be* no longer the same.

In that case, my code will break silently.

Is it safe to always assume that the above two `NULL` strings are always the same?

Comment: `null` just means that it doesn't point to any reference. So null will always be null. It can't change unless you change it on your own

Comment: Strange question.

Comment: In a managed environment I do not see how null is undefined behavior.

Comment: `NULL` doesn't have a *universal* meaning. Just because in some languages (say, SQL, since I see you've done some mysql stuff on here in the past) `NULL` has a meaning closely associated with "unknown" or "undefined" behaviour, it doesn't mean the same is true of C#'s `null`.

Comment: In C# and .NET, `null` has a well-defined meaning, and does not mean "undefined behavior".

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: why is it strange? If your application relies on it you have to know if it's something you can rely on, or if it might break under certain circumstances or in future versions of the .NET framework. Btw, this is even true for VB.NET where `Nothing` really means unspecified/undefined(or default value).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that's documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If both a and b are null, the method returns true.

and this method is used when you use `==`, which is mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx).

> calls the static `Equals(String, String)` method

Comment: @MickyD Make that 10. i need to use up my upvotes for the day

Comment: ok ok...11.  I do like the static `Equals`. Only discovered that recently ;)

Comment: @MickyD: i like the static `Equals` because of  [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks(v=vs.110).aspx) which enables to compare in a case insensitive manner(as opposed to `==`) and because it avoids a `NullReferenceException` which could happen with the instance method.

Comment: Agreed good sir. (less verbose than `string.Compare (...)` too)

Answer (score 2):

If both strings are null, the method always return true because **==** are used for reference comparison. In simple words, == checks if both objects point to the same memory location.

I tried this example with java `str1.Equals(str2)` and this returns **Null Pointer Exception**, because .Equals evaluates to the comparison of values in the objects.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Operator overloading means that you cannot *assume* that `==` is always reference comparison. `String` is a class that *does* [overload it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You are getting a `NullPointerException` because you are trying to access the `.Equals` method of a `null` object, not because you compare the values. Try with `string.Equals(str1, str2)`, you'll get `true`.

Comment: Also, it's a `NullReferenceException`, not a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Sorry, the point of srt1.Equals(str2) is in java context and in java it returns NullPointerException. I qoute that example just to make clear understanding. However in c#, string.Equals(str1, str2) returns true, beacause it checks equality on the basis of content.